# Apply Border-Radius To Scrollbars with CSS

Tags: html, scrollbar, css

To put it simple, this is what i want (obtained on a Webkit Browser using *-webkit-scrollbar*) :

[image]

And this is what I get on Opera (Firefox doesn't apply the border radius to the scrollbar either, but still applies the border) :

[image]

**Is there a simple way to make the border not disappear under the scrollbar ?**

I dont need the fancy style of *-webkit-scrollbar* but i would like the page to look clean and symmetric...

Comment: Neat and easy those days `::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb { border-radius: 10px; }`

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I've been having the same issue. It's not the most elegant of solutions but, simply put a smaller div inside your outer box so the scroll bar doesn't overlap the outer box.

Like this code copied from [this pen](https://codepen.io/M_J_Robbins/pen/eKFha):

```css
.box {
  height: 200px;
  width: 250px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #666;
  padding: 6px 0px;
  background: #ccc;
}

.box-content {
  height: 200px;
  width: 250px;
  overflow: auto;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="box-content">
    <ol>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: worked great with a minor tweak. Since the content which had scrollbar was huge, I had to make sure the content height is less than the outer div container height.

Comment: overflow:hidden on the outer box

Answer (score 75):

Put the content that needs to be scrolled in a `div` with `overflow: auto`. Around that content `div` put a `div` with your rounded corners and `overflow: hidden`.

Now you can see the scroll bar but its outer corners are hidden and
are not disturbing the rounded corners of the outer `div`.

Example:

```js
// Insert placeholder text
document.querySelector('.inner').innerHTML = 'Text<br>'.repeat(20);
```

```css
.outer {
  width: 150pt;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 15pt;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.inner {
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        <!-- lots of text here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you want to use this for content with an unknown height, setting the inner height to auto won't work. In this case you should inherit the height from the parent element instead to make it work.

Comment: As @burnaDLX says, it won't work unless you constrain the inner size to the outer size such as  "height: 100%; " or fixed size as "height: 200px" (that's <= to the outer height)  in the example. (do the same for width if adapting for horizontal scrolling)    Otherwise the inner size just grows to accommodate the contents and overflows in the outer container, which has its overflow hiddren.

Comment: much appreciated sir

Answer (score 48):

Google implemented something like this when showing their web apps.

[image]

With the help of the inspect element and copy-paste, I came with the codes below.

```css
ul::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: red;
  border: 4px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-clip: padding-box;  
}

ul::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 16px;
}

ul {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 350px;
  max-height: 300px;
  background-color: #ddd;

  border-radius: 8px;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 13px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>google.com</li>
  <li>facebook.com</li>
  <li>twitter.com</li>
  <li>instagram.com</li>
  <li>linkedin.com</li>
  <li>reddit.com</li>
  <li>whatsapp.com</li>
  <li>tumblr.com</li>
  <li>skype.com</li>
</ul>
```

I don't consider myself a CSS expert, so hopefully, someone will explain how these things work.

Or you can check the docs on MDN:

- [`::-webkit-scrollbar`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-scrollbar)
- [`background-clip`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip)

Comment: This is chrome-only and not cross-browser

Comment: Based on which browser the inspect element was ran on, webkit and such css styles may be applied based on browser implementation of the super set of css for the element. The super set may contain other syling statements which might be applied only on the correct browser. Hence without the source, reverse engineering by inspect element would have to be done on each browser, where compatibility is required.

Comment: @vsync I've tested the code in Safari and Firefox. Works like a charm now.

Answer (score 4):

The fancy horizontal scrollbar with a border radius.

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
   width: 10px;
   height: 10px;
 }

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #888;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #555;
}
```

The same in SCSS

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;

  &-track {
    background: #f1f1f1;
  }

  &-thumb {
    background: #888;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;

    &:hover {
      background: #555;
    }
  }
}
```

The test screenshot is attached below:
[image]

Comment: This was amazing! Worked 100%, I added border-radius: 10px; to  ::-webkit-scrollbar-track to get the desired rounded scrollbar track

Answer (score 2):

This is the same as @Madan Sapkota and for the exception of border-radius: 10px; in the scrollbar and track classes no inner div needed

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
   width: 10px;
   height: 10px;
   border-radius: 10px;
 }

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #f1f1f1;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #888;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #555;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**slim with rounded corners**

```css
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    .scrollbar {
        overflow: auto;
        width: 0.5em !important;
        scroll-behavior: smooth !important;
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) !important;
        background-color: darkgrey !important;
        outline: 1px solid slategrey !important;
        border-radius: 10px !important;
    }
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0.5em !important;
    scroll-behavior: smooth !important;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) !important;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: darkgrey !important;
    outline: 1px solid slategrey !important;
    border-radius: 10px !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="scrollbar" style="height: 600px">
   <h1>Scrollbar is slim with rounded corners</h1>
   <br/>
   <br/>
   <br/>
   <br/>
   <h1>Scrollbar is slim with rounded corners</h1>
   <br/>
   <br/>
   <br/>
   <br/>
   <h1>Scrollbar is slim with rounded corners</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: This works in chrome but not in firefox, as the question requested.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a slim scroller here it is **SCSS CODE**

```
.custom-scroll {
  overflow: auto;
  scrollbar-color: #c1c1c1 #e6e6e6;
  scrollbar-width: thin;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 10px !important;
  &::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #c1c1c1;
    border-radius: 10px !important;
  }
  &::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background: #a8a8a8;
  }
  &::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: #e6e6e6;
    border-left: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 10px !important;
  }
  &::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 7px;
    scroll-behavior: smooth !important;
  }
}
```

plain **css code** is here

```
.custom-scroll {
  overflow: auto;
  scrollbar-color: #c1c1c1 #e6e6e6;
  scrollbar-width: thin;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 10px !important;
}
.custom-scroll::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #c1c1c1;
  border-radius: 10px !important;
}
.custom-scroll::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #a8a8a8;
}
.custom-scroll::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #e6e6e6;
  border-left: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 10px !important;
}
.custom-scroll::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 7px;
  scroll-behavior: smooth !important;
}
```

Html code lines

```
<div class="custom-scroll" style="max-height:300px">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae quam vel consectetur enim aliquam unde libero sint, exercitationem voluptate doloribus, quasi veritatis accusantium itaque. In beatae recusandae possimus ea quae.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae quam vel consectetur enim aliquam unde libero sint, exercitationem voluptate doloribus, quasi veritatis accusantium itaque. In beatae recusandae possimus ea quae.</p>
</div>
```

Out put will look like this on **Light and Dark** skin

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Old topic, but was still accurate for me. Neat and easy those days

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```css
/* width */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 20px;
}

/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px grey;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: red;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>scrollbar border</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

Would be nice if you could supply a fiddle. Nevertheless, you shoud try changing the box-sizing on the container to border-box (if not already done):

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

Comment: This CSS property is unrelated to the problem

Comment: Or just `border-radius: 0;`