# How to make rounded corners with overflow scroll without messing up the scroll bar?

Tags: html, css, scroll

When making a `div` with rounded corners, and having content inside that `div` with `overflow-y: scroll;` the scroll appears but it's going outside the rounded corners

See Example 1 for the problem

There is a solution here about having an inner `div` - https://stackoverflow.com/a/17491591/3316338 but the content in that example still gets cut

But I tried that. I tried making an outer `div` and an inner `div`, with the inner one not reaching the border radius, and that fixes the scroll, but then another problem appears where my content will be cut depending how much distance there is between top of the outer `div` and the inner `div`. See Example 2

Example 1 http://jsfiddle.net/9wkqgy47/4/
Example 2 http://jsfiddle.net/9wkqgy47/3/

I expect to scroll to not go outside the rounded borders and the content not being cut by the inner `div`
Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apply Border-Radius To Scrollbars with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16676166/apply-border-radius-to-scrollbars-with-css)

Comment: @ChrisW. I've edited my question. In the example the content still gets cut