# Is there a way to move custom HTML scrollbar behind a div

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, code-snippets

I have some code snippets on my blog post [here](https://blog.zoneofcode.com/2019/01/custom-fonts-on-blogger.html).

There I have custom scrollbar defined with this code below:

```
/* width */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 20px;
}

/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px grey;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #0ef; 
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

The place where I have included the snippet is a custom div element with border radius of `2em`. Now the custom scrollbar looks some bulged out as you can see in the image below:

[image: Bulged out scrollbar]

How can I send the scrollbar behind the `<div>` so that the extra scrollbar may be removed?

**P.S.**: The border radius of the `<div>` should be maintained.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apply Border-Radius To Scrollbars with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16676166/apply-border-radius-to-scrollbars-with-css)

Comment: @dakshh My question is entirely different!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a small div inside your outer div and make that the container of your scroll bar to stop the bulging out of these scroll bars eg. [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gjoL0q1y/2/) like

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
   ..content
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.outer{
  max-height:200px;
  width:250px;
  border-radius:10px; 
  padding:0px 0px;
  background:#ccc;
}
.inner{
  white-space: nowrap;
  width:250px;
  max-height:200px;
  overflow-x:scroll;
  overflow-y:hidden;
  border-radius:8px;
}
/* width */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 20px;
}

/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px grey;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #0ef; 
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
 tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
 quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
 consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
 cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
 proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That works but how to attach that scrollbar to he bottom of the inner div. It seems a bit raised up.

Comment: @Gourav that's just the border and padding, you can change that according to your recommendations

Comment: OK I'll try tomorrow. It's time to sleep :)