# Clip scrollbar inside rounded div corners CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to clip a scrollbar inside a div so that it does not spill out over the rounded corners. Please see the code below for the demonstration of the issue.

Is it possible for the scrollbar to stay in the same position, but for the excess to be 'cut' off by the rounded corners as if it was contained within the div borders and not placed over them?

```css
div {
  margin: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
}

p {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Item 1</p>
  <p>Item 2</p>
  <p>Item 3</p>
  <p>Item 4</p>
  <p>Item 5</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apply Border-Radius To Scrollbars with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16676166/apply-border-radius-to-scrollbars-with-css)

Comment: I faced that problem in ioBroker where I couldn't place an overflow box in a simple way. 
Since for me it was sufficient to display the track itself adding transparency to both scrollbar and scrollbar-track did the trick.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to wrap your content like this

```css
.main {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.test {
  height: 200px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
p {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="test">
    <p>Item 1</p>
    <p>Item 2</p>
    <p>Item 3</p>
    <p>Item 4</p>
    <p>Item 5</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are multple ways but the easiest and better way is to wrap your scroll div and apply style. It will slove your problem.

```css
div.wrapper {
  margin: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1.2rem 0.05rem  1.2rem 0
}

div.scroll{
 overflow-x: hidden;
 overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 200px;

}

p {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 10px 10px;
  margin: 0;
}

/* width */
div.scroll::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 15px;

}

/* Track */
div.scroll::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px grey; 
  border-radius: 30px;
}
 
/* Handle */
div.scroll::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: gray; 
  border-radius: 30px;
  
}

/* Handle on hover */
div.scroll::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #b30000; 
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class=scroll>
  <p>Item 1</p>
  <p>Item 2</p>
  <p>Item 3</p>
  <p>Item 4</p>
  <p>Item 5</p>
  <p>Item 5</p>
  <p>Item 5</p>
  <p>Item 5</p>
  <p>Item 5</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to hide overflow content using `overflow:hidden`

```css
.root {
  margin: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.scrollIt {
  height: 250px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
p {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
 <div class="scrollIt">
  <p>Item 1</p>
  <p>Item 2</p>
  <p>Item 3</p>
  <p>Item 4</p>
  <p>Item 5</p>
 </div>
</div>
```