# How can I make an scrollbar to adapt to border-radius container?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a container with overflow-y: auto, and I want it to look like this:

[image]

But it looks like this:

[image]

I don't know if you can see it but in the second image the scrollbar comes outof the container. I want to keep it inside but I don't know how.

This is my code:

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0.5em;

    &-track {
        background-color: transparent;
    }

    &-thumb {
        border-radius: 50vh;
        background-color: #c0c0c0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share your html code?

Comment: You can do this by using two divs with parent and child div.

Comment: try check this it might be your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60162891/clip-scrollbar-inside-rounded-div-corners-css