# creating padding in textarea scroll-bar

Tags: css

The issue is that my text area looks like this[image: a text area with a border radius, however the scroll bar is overflowing out of the textarea's border]

The Aim is to reduce the scroll height, so it fits in its box.
There is padding in the text area, but this doesn't apply to the scroll bar.
I have seen you can use scroll-{height, padding, margin, start}, just can't seem to correct it, probs because of my lack of experience with those properties.

```css
textarea {
  resize: none;
  scroll-padding: 50px 0 50px 0;
  width: 450px;
  display: block;
  padding: 12px 15px 15px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  border: 2px solid #d0adff;
  outline: none;
  font-family: acumin-pro, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  color: rgb(90, 90, 90);
}
```

```html
<textarea placeholder="Message" name="message" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
```

Comment: Read this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50817727/change-scrollbar-height

Comment: Another option would be : https://stackoverflow.com/a/17491591/630203

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I found is to hide it.

```
textarea::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I misunderstood what you're asking for but I think this would do:

Note: For some reason the scrollbar hides when you don't add the background colour to it, so just customize it as you want so it looks nice :)

```css
 textarea {
      resize: none;
      scroll-padding: 50px 0 50px 0;
      width: 450px;
      display: block;
      padding: 12px 15px 15px;
      border-radius: 30px;
      border: 2px solid #d0adff;
      outline: none;
      font-family: acumin-pro, sans-serif;
      font-size: 1.3em;
      color: rgb(90, 90, 90);
}
textarea::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
}

textarea::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #f1f1f1;
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

textarea::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #888;
}
```

```html
<textarea placeholder="Message" name="message" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the answers, I found it easier to style a new around the text area, and set the border and outline of the text area to none.