# Scrollbar of bootstrap dropdown menu problem with border radius property

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

Scroll bar of bootstrap dropdown menu is stay outs the box when using border radius property. How to fix?

> Example code and preview:
> https://www.codeply.com/p/7P8MsVnOG7

```
<div class="container py-4">
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">Item</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">Item</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">Item</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">Item</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">Item</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">Item</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">Item</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">Item</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">Item</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">Item</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">Item</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">Item</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.dropdown-menu {
    max-height: 280px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    border-radius:30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an extra outer container which will have rounded corners, but hidden overflow, and show scrollbar on inner container. To trigger dropdown menu, move `dropdown-menu` class to the outer container, so that `ul` remains, which you'll need to style to bring back the original look (remove extra padding/margin etc. with utility classes, also needed to throw in `border-radius: 30px !important`, because BS seems to override it upon toggling..):

solution based upon: [Apply Border-Radius To Scrollbars with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16676166/apply-border-radius-to-scrollbars-with-css)

```css
.dropdown-menu {
  border-radius: 30px !important;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown-menu-scrollbar {
  max-height: 280px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="container py-4">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <ul class="ps-0 dropdown-menu-scrollbar">
        <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">Item</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">Item</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">Item</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">Item</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">Item</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">Item</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">Item</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">Item</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">Item</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">Item</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">Item</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">Item</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```